# $k$-algebra points of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm seeking clarification on a sentence I'm reading. In the appendix on algebraic geometry of Milne's "Algebraic Groups" he writes: "For an algebraic scheme $X$ over $k$, we let $X(R)$ denote the set of points of $X$ with coordinates in a $k$-algebra $R$,

$X(R):=Hom(Spm(R),X)$."

What does this mean? How can $X(R)$ be viewed as a subset of $X$?

Comment: This is a definition. $X$ is not a set, so it doesn't make sense to talk about subsets of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Qiaochu Yaun mentioned in a comment this is a definition, but admittedly the notion of "points" can be quite confusing here.

Usually to make the distinction between these points and the usual points, one calls the points you defined **$R$-valued points** of $X$. Let me denote by $Y=\mathrm{Spec}R$ throughout.

Let me motivate this terminology. Let us start with $R=k$ and $X=\mathrm{Spec}A$ with $A=k[x_1,\cdots, x_n]/(f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_m)$ a $k$-algebra. Let me write by abuse of notation $k=Y$ in this case. 
Then any morphism in $\mathrm{Hom}(k,X)$ is equivalent to a homorphism $\Phi\in \mathrm{Hom}(A,k)$. Moreover $\Phi$ is obtained by determining $a_i=\Phi(x_i)$. But we must moreover have $f_j(a_i)=0$ for all $j=1, \cdots, m$. In other words
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(Y,X)\simeq\{(a_1, \cdots, a_n)\in k^n\mid \forall 1\leq j\leq m:f_j(a_i)=0\}
$$
The set on the right hand side is called the set of **$k$-rational points** of $X$. In case, for example $k=\mathbb{C}$ (or any algebraically closed field), this set coincides with the set of *closed* points of $X$. In the more general case of $X$ being a $k$-scheme of finite type, understanding $\mathrm{Hom}(k,X)$  again as the set of $k$-rational points is completely analogous (by usage of an affine chart).

Using the notion of $k$-rational points as a motivation, one can do a similar analysis for a general $k$-algebra $R$. Then again if $A=k[x_1,\cdots, x_n]/(f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_m)$, one finds that

$$
\mathrm{Hom}(Y,X)\simeq\{(a_1, \cdots, a_n)\in R^n\mid \forall 1\leq j\leq m:f_j(a_i)=0\}
$$
for this reason one in general calls this the set of **$R$-valued points**. Again the case of $X$ a general $k$-scheme of finite type is straightforward. But actually, one can also drop the "finite type" notion and work with this set in the abstract. One should then be careful not get confused since these so called "points" might not have **any** meaningful relationship to points of the (underlying set of the ) scheme.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the points in the underlying topological space should be referred to as the "physical points." I think the $k$-rational points coincide with the $k$-valued points if $k$ is arbitrary (no need for algebraically closed). Your last sentence is particularly helpful as I've never seen it written explicitly in expositions of this topic.